# Maven insist using local parent rather than remote WITHOUT relativePath mentioned

Tags: maven

I have a test project which is based on a parent project. This parent is build beforehand and is available on local artifactory server. The parent project is not available locally and this should stay this way.

As you see I am not using the relativePath element.

Still, when running "mvn clean install -U" I get an error about missing parent.

```
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.test.example:test:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.test:projects-parent:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 10 -> [Help 2]
```

The test project pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>projects-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
    ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    ...
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the parent pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>projects-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0/maven-model/maven.html#class_parent), the default value for `<relativePath>` is `../pom.xml`, so Maven will look locally first.

If you want to force the lookup to occur in your repository manager, use this trick:

```
   <parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>projects-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!— This forces a lookup against the repo —>
    </parent>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error:
Non-resolvable parent POM for com.test.xxx-root:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.test:projects-parent:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 7, column 13 -> [Help 2]

Comment: Did you do a `mvn -N install` on the parent?

Comment: Not sure i got you. I did try to use -N when running the mvn clean install which failed....

Comment: Well, since  `<relativePath/>` forces Maven to look up the artifact in the repository (and if it isn't there, fetch it from network), installing the parent POM *only* (`-N`) to your local repository should resolve the problem. Did you stand in the parent's directory when doing the command? Did it install properly? Another way of doing it is to stand in the top directory (assuming you have a multi-module build) and do a `mvn install -pl :projects-parent`.

Comment: I do not want to install it locally. I want to use it directly from the server, as it is done always in many projects with parent project, such spring boot

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. Maven always installs dependencies and any parent to your local repo that isn’t part your reactor. If you download any Maven Spring Boot example project and build it, take a look in your local repo and you’ll find the Spring parent POM there. The *only* thing `<relativePath>` controls is where to look for the parent if it’s not in the default place (`..`).